# Error starting LoggerServer when using IDEA development : io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal packet

Tags: java, apache-dolphinscheduler

LoggerServer starts with an error as follows, but my colleague does not. Our Idea, JDK and Maven versions are almost the same, and the code is copied from Git.

Error:

```
org.apache.dolphinscheduler.remote.handler.NettyServerHandler - exceptionCaught : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal packet [magic]80
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal packet [magic]80
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:421)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal packet [magic]80
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.remote.codec.NettyDecoder.checkMagic(NettyDecoder.java:125)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.remote.codec.NettyDecoder.decode(NettyDecoder.java:57)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:366)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, I changed the port to 50051.